# How to find multi-word string from string, and label it in python?

Tags: python, nlp, string-matching, preprocessor, labeling

For example, the sentence is `"The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis"`, and I need to label the `"corporate balance sheets"` which is a substring found from given sentence.

So, the pattern that I need to find is:

```
"corporate balance sheets"
```

Given the string:

```
"The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis".
```

The output label sequence I want will be:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There are a bunch of sentences(more than 2GB), and a bunch of patterns I need to find. I have no idea how to do that efficiently in python. Can someone give me a good algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all words in the substring have to match, you can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to check that and update the appropriate indices as you iterate through the sentence:

```
def encode(sub, sent):
    subwords, sentwords = sub.split(), sent.split()
    res = [0 for _ in sentwords]    
    for i, word in enumerate(sentwords[:-len(subwords) + 1]):
        if all(x == y for x, y in zip(subwords, sentwords[i:i + len(subwords)])):
            for j in range(len(subwords)):
                res[i + j] = 1
    return res


sub = "corporate balance sheets"
sent = "The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis"
print(encode(sub, sent))
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

sent = "The corporate balance data are available on an annual basis sheets"
print(encode(sub, sent))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**List Comprehension and using split:**

```
import re
lst=[]
search_word = 'corporate balance sheets'
p = re.compile(search_word)
sentence="The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis"

lst=[1 for i in range(len(search_word.split()))]
vect=[ lst if items == '__match_word' else 0 for items in re.sub(p,'__match_word',sentence).split()]
vectlstoflst=[[vec] if isinstance(vec,int) else vec for vec in vect]
flattened = [val for sublist in vectlstoflst for val in sublist]
```

**Output:**

```
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Sentence ="The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis sheets"

**Output**

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: doesn't work if there's a word from search_word but not in a complete match?

Comment: if "sheets" occur independently at the end of sentence but not with "corporate balance"

Comment: if sentence is "The corporate balance data are available on an annual basis sheets" then output is [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: @rokrokss, Can you give an example where it is not working?

Comment: with the previous example on the comment, the last "sheets" should not be labeled. the algorithm only need to label whole matched pattern from start to end.

Comment: "The corporate balance data are available on an annual basis sheets" will be all 0.

Comment: @rokrokss, Check now, if the search word is in the same order in sentence then it would be a match else not.

Comment: This will still fail with *"The corporate balance sheets data are available on an annual basis sheets"*.